# label in LaunchScreen displays improperly if upon turning google maps on or opening the phone call bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints

label in LaunchScreen displays improperly if upon turning google maps on or opening the phone call bar, 
my label **align center x** , and **align center y**, if i remove **align center y** and give align it to the top view the label will be corrupted, but the problem that the label will not be centered on all devices.

So how can i keep the label centered without corruption.

[image]

This a screenshot for my constraints

[image]

Comment: Hey, it looks like you're using slicing for this asset. can you go to this asset and make sure it's not sliced, or just delete it and add it to the assets list again?

Comment: @TalCohen it's not an asset, it's label

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of its constraints?

Comment: @TalCohen i update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem you only need to set your constraints to top, leading, trailing, Bottom to zero.

[image: constraints]